# How to find document value contains % or $ in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find the document where path and folder contain % or $. 
I've tried

```
collection.find( { $or: [ { "folder": /.*%.*/ }, { "path": /.*%.*/ } ] } )
```

but I can't apply same for $.

This is sample data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52fae0e3dbdb97e52cc8af"),
    "title" : null,
    "path" : "/ho%me",
    "folder": "test"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52fae0e3dbdb97e52cc8af"),
    "title" : null,
    "path" : "/home",
    "folder": "te$st"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52fae0e3dbdb97e52cc8af"),
    "title" : null,
    "path" : "/home%%%",
    "folder": "test$$$&&&%%%"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52fae0e3dbdb97e52cc8af"),
    "title" : null,
    "path" : "/home",
    "folder": "test"
}
```

Comment: Did you try `$regex` operations?

Comment: No, can you help me with that? since I'm new to MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `$` is a special sign in regex, you have to [escape](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping#escaping) it.

```
collection.find( { $or: [
    { "folder": /.*(%|\$).*/ },
    { "path": /.*(%|\$).*/ } 
] } )
```